# Why can't I iterate and print the contents of vector after using reserve to allocate storage?

Tags: c++

Given below is a simple program which takes input into  a vector and trying to print the vector using iterator. Why doesn't it print the vector?? Everything seems to be alright.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n,m,i;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(m);
    vector<int>::iterator it;

    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
     cin >> v[i];
   // for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    // cout << v[i];
    for(it = v.begin();it != v.end();it++)
      cout << *(it);  
    return 0;
}
```

If I input "4 3 1 2 3" why doesn't the program give any output?

Comment: `v.reserve()` doesn't add elements to the vector, it just reserves memory as an optimization. You probably need `v.resize()`

Comment: ... Which means the iterators are the only thing in this program that isn't behaving in some undefined manner.

Comment: On giving input, 4 3 1 2 3 it doesn't give any output

Comment: @VedantDixit [This reveals that reserve() doesn't do what you think it does](https://www.ideone.com/G9IoJ7).  See the runtime exception (`std::out_of_range`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) does not do the same thing as [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize). `reserve` is a hint to the allocator to try to "preallocate" the space needed to store a number of elements. As far as the vector is concerned, it's still size 0, which means its iterators will represent a range of 0 elements.

Change `v.reserve(m);` to `v.resize(m);`, and your issue should be resolved.

Comment: Xirema on printing *v.begin() and *(v.begin()+1) it however prints 1 and 2

Comment: @VedantDixit you are operating outside the bounds of the `vector`. This is undefined behaviour. Maybe it works. Maybe it doesn't, maybe the program calls in a drone strike on the neighbour's cat.

Comment: @VedantDixit When you call `reserve`, the backing memory is created, and the iterators may or may not point to valid memory. If they do, then your program might work when you try to perform operations on them. This does not change the fact that the behavior of your program is depending on *Undefined Behavior*, which means that **you have no guarantee that your program will work correctly any other time you run your program, or even any other time you compile it**. Follow my advice, and research what your STL function calls are actually doing.